# How can I use a .txt instead of a list in code?

Tags: discord, pycharm, discord.py, bots, nextcord

Im I've just started coding and made my own discord bot. Now I am trying to make him a bit clearer. I have huge lists with possible answer-outputs for the bot and dont know how to separate them into a txt with a random line output because of the {message_author} part. Maybe someone could help please?
Thank you and have a good day.

[small example of the {message_author} part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpW2p.png)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Replacing lists with text files is great practice! However, please don't post screenshot of your code. Instead, copy-paste your code directly in the question, and put the code between three backticks: ``` ```   Please use the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72288005/edit) button to edit your question to add the code.

Comment: Instead of using screenshots of your code, please write the code in the question itself as it makes the question more readable. You can use triple backticks in front and back of your code to make it a code block

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fill-in text for `message_author` in the text file, then replace this fill-in text with `message_author` in the code.

For instance:

**messages.txt**

```
Du auch mal hier $name$.
Oh guten Abend, $name$. Ich hoffe du hast Spaß.
```

**code.py**

```py
import random

def build_greetings_list(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        l = list(f)
    return l

def random_hello(greetings_list, name):
    hello = random.choice(greetings_list)
    return hello.replace('$name$', name)

def main():
    greetings_list = build_greetings_list('messages.txt')
    for name in ('Alice', 'Betty', 'Chen', 'Deedee'):
        print(random_hello(greetings_list, name))

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
Du auch mal hier Alice.
Oh guten Abend, Betty. Ich hoffe du hast Spaß.
Du auch mal hier Chen.
Du auch mal hier Deedee.
```